# How to split a series into multiple columns with a separator python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I have a csv with one single column and I want to get a multiple columns dataframe in python to work on it.
My test.csv is the following (in one single column):

```
ID;location;level;temperature;season
001;leeds;63;11;autumn
002;sydney;36;11;spring
003;lyon;250;11;autumn
004;edmonton;645;8;autumn
```

I want to get the information in a Data Frame like this:

```
ID      Location   Level  Temperature   Season
001     Leeds      63          11       Autumn
002     Sydney     36          11       Sprint
003     Lyon       250         11       Autumn
004     Edmonton   645         8        Autumn
```

I've tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'test.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
df= df.str.split(';', expand=True)
```

But I've got this error: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'` this was an attempt to use it as in Series. Is the similar way to do it in dataframes?

I would like to know if there is a pythonic way to do it or I should iterate per rows.
Is it str.split deprecated? I found it that is for Series but seems to be deprecated.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: `pd.read_csv(r'test.csv', header=0, index_col=0, sep=';')`?

Comment: Thank you Joachim! it worked beautifully!